# Azure Synapse Database To And From Netezza - Most Efficient Approach

Tags: java, database, azure, cloud, netezza

We were hoping to load data to Azure Synapse (Cloud) from Netezza and vice versa using Qlik however we are finding the performance is unacceptable. What is the fastest way to achieve this?

We have some in-house tools written in Java that perform this task however I have no clue how to run this code on the native cloud environment, or whether this is even feasible.

I do not have much experience with Cloud so any guidance about where to spend my time to get to my goal quicker would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From Netezza the fastest is ‘create external table as select….’

If your Netezza is new enough (CP4D) you can even refer to a file location ON cloud, but otherwise you may need a (fast) file stores on both Azure and on-Prem

A bit of reading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-external-tables?tabs=hadoop

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.load.doc/c_load_create_external_tbl_syntax.html

Basically you will need to use UTF8 (aka ‘internal’ on Netezza) and choose 5 special characters:

1. an escape character (usually ‘\’)
2. a column delimiter (usually the TAB character)
3. a row delimiter (usually new-line)
4. a string delimiter (usually double quotes ‘“‘)
5. a NULL indicator character (usually a star ‘*’)

Choose the same 5 characters in both ends and do a binary file-transfer of some sort (xFTPx, HTTP or a dedicated Azure Copy tool of some sort) an you should be good :)

Comment: We tried something like this last year but had trouble with newlines in the actual data. I wonder if the newline issue is now resolved as someone from Microsoft suggested column data cannot contain newline in this approach

Comment: Too bad - works fine in Netezza… you will probably have to BASE64 encode or HEX encode those string columns in the SELECT statement above (essentially treat them as binary data) and decode on the receiving end

Comment: Do you have a link to any website that shows how to do this from netezza to blob storage?   I have used (  insert into select from external file) before